# Hive client for Python 3.x

Tags: python, hadoop, python-3.x, hive

is it possible to connect to hadoop and run hive queries using Python 3.x? I am using Python 3.4.1.

I found out that it can be done as written here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-Python

However, I cannot install hive module because it says that 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hive'.

Answer (score 0):

If you have HiveServer2 installed you can use [pyhs2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyhs2/0.4.1).
Or if you're execution your script locally, than you can use subprocess and catch the output of `hive -e your_query;`.