# How to connect with Hiveserver2 using Python 3.4.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, hive, python-3.4

I need to connect to the Hiveserver2 from Python 3.4.5 and the code is being executed on the hadoop cluster itself. Usually, I execute `hive -e "some query"` from command line. From other servers, we connect to Hiveserver2 using username only mechanism providing IP and port. However, that should not be necessary as here I am running the code on same server.

I have tried the following:

1. [Access Hive Data Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722372/access-hive-data-using-python)
2. https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/165
3. [How to connect to Hadoop Hive through python via pyhs2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953764/how-to-connect-to-hadoop-hive-through-python-via-pyhs2)
4. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/impyla

but no success. I am getting error at connection stage itself. I can share errors if anyone requires.

If nothing else, it would be great if someone can elaborate on the answer to 
[Hive client for Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261582/hive-client-for-python-3-x)

Comment: Including a minimal code example that demonstrates the problem and the error/trace would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help from a friend and little bit tweaking of online available answers using impala.dbapi solved the issue:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect(host='localhost', port = 10000,auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('show databases')
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(type(results))
print(results)
```